# React TypeScript: Saving a base64 string to useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to save a base64 string to state but im getting an unknown type error, how do I assign the type?

```
import React, {useState, useRef}  from 'react';


const App: React.FC = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState({country: '', firstName: '', middleInitial: '', lastName: '', dobDay: '', dobMonth: '', dobYear:'', email:'', phoneCode: '', phoneNumber: '', documentCountry: '', documentType: '', frontDoc: '', backDoc: '', selfie: ''});


  const toBase64 = (file: any) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });

  const setFrontDoc = async(event: any) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const frontDoc = await toBase64(file)
    setState({...state, frontDoc}); // <========= Error here!
  }
```

The error is

```
Argument of type '{ frontDoc: unknown; country: string; firstName: string; middleInitial: string; lastName: string; dobDay: string; dobMonth: string; dobYear: string; email: string; phoneCode: string; phoneNumber: string; documentCountry: string; documentType: string; backDoc: string; selfie: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ country: string; firstName: string; middleInitial: string; lastName: string; dobDay: string; dobMonth: string; dobYear: string; email: string; phoneCode: string; phoneNumber: string; documentCountry: string; documentType: string; frontDoc: string; backDoc: string; selfie: string; }>'.
  Type '{ frontDoc: unknown; country: string; firstName: string; middleInitial: string; lastName: string; dobDay: string; dobMonth: string; dobYear: string; email: string; phoneCode: string; phoneNumber: string; documentCountry: string; documentType: string; backDoc: string; selfie: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ country: string; firstName: string; middleInitial: string; lastName: string; dobDay: string; dobMonth: string; dobYear: string; email: string; phoneCode: string; phoneNumber: string; documentCountry: string; documentType: string; frontDoc: string; backDoc: string; selfie: string; }'.
    Types of property 'frontDoc' are incompatible.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I have tried

```
const frontDoc: string = await toBase64(file);
```

but i get the error `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: Why are you calling frontDoc inside frontDoc ??

Comment: good call, I've fixed that issue but the original issue remains the same

Comment: console your frontDoc and let me know, I guess your setState executing before frontDoc gets executed.

Comment: the console prints the bas64 fine `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...`

Comment: Ok now don't wait for it const frontDoc = await toBase64(file), use some dummy data and check where has your error occurred. My guess is  setState({...state, frontDoc}); executing before your  const frontDoc = await toBase64(file)

Comment: same issue if i make it thenable: `toBase64(file).then(value => { setState({...state, value});});` I also tried an old time out

Comment: Could you try `Promise<string>` instead of `Promise`? It should typescript to the types so it a kids unknown.

Comment: `Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | PromiseLike<string> | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | PromiseLike<string> | undefined'.ts(2345)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **as string**

```
const frontDoc = await toBase64(file) as string
```